# How to connect Jetty WebSocket Client Through Http Proxy

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I'm trying to configure my Jetty WebSocket client to go through a proxy, is this currently possible I went through the API of WebSocketClientFactory WebSocketClient but couldn't find API for this. Could it be configurable through system properties?

Comment: Not currently possible: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409516